# VerifyError in release build

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've got an Andoid app which, when built in debug mode, appears to run just fine (using an emulator or a physical phone).

When I rebuild the very same code in release mode however, I always get the following crash on startup (again, everywhere - no matter if it is a physical phone or an emulator) :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.distorted.magic/org.distorted.playui.PlayActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in org.distorted.magic:layout/play: Binary XML file line #12 in org.distorted.magic:layout/play: Error inflating class org.distorted.playui.PlayView
(...)                 
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class org.distorted.library.main.InternalChildrenList: void org.distorted.library.main.InternalChildrenList.addSortingByBuckets(org.distorted.library.main.DistortedNode) failed to verify: void org.distorted.library.main.InternalChildrenList.addSortingByBuckets(org.distorted.library.main.DistortedNode): [0x19] type Undefined unexpected as arg to if-eqz/if-nez (declaration of 'org.distorted.library.main.InternalChildrenList' appears in /data/app/~~3uwbjOmT6qVqIWfcJWDV3g==/org.distorted.magic-awjTiIFTfzpMWKypA3V6hQ==/base.apk!classes4.dex)
```

The method rejected by the Verifier does not appear to be using anything special:

```
  private void addSortingByBuckets(DistortedNode newChild)
    {
    int i;
    long bucket = newChild.getBucket();
    boolean thisSame,lastSame = false;

    for(i=0; i<mNumChildren; i++)
      {
      thisSame= (mChildren.get(i).getBucket()==bucket);
      if( lastSame && !thisSame ) break;
      lastSame = thisSame;
      }

    mChildren.add(i,newChild);
    mNumChildren++;
    }
```

Furthermore, I have switched off ProGuard (minifyEnabled=false) in build.gradle so that the build targets now look like this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
```

And I am still getting the crash.

I suspect the problem might be environmental (something with the toolchain installed on the comp) because the very same code, when compiled on another machine in release mode, runs just fine.

Would anybody have any pointers?

Comment: Maybe you use local build cache? Remove all build directories, ~/.gradle/caches, and invalidate restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the crucial difference between the two machines which triggers this issue. It is the version of Android Gradle Plugin (or the version of the Gradle itself).

If AGP is set to 8.2.2 and Gradle to 8.2 (which is the default in new fresh Android Studio installs) then this issue is there.

If I downgrade AGP to 8.1.4 and Gradle to 8.1.1, the issue disappears. I have also tested several AGPs from the '7' line ( 7.4.1, 7.2.2 ) with '7' line of Gradle, and also - no issue anymore.

Version of JDK doesn't seem to matter. 21, 17, 16, 15, 11 - all work (or not) depending only on the versions of AGP and Gradle.